# Relationship between velocity vector and speed?

Tags: vectors, kinematics

[image: Velocity vector triangle]

Hi all,

I'm not too sure if this belongs in the Physics or Maths stack exchange but i feel like this is the most suitable place for it.

Could someone explain why the sum of two velocity vectors (i and j component) is equal to the speed?

Sorry if this diagram or statement doesn't make sense. I've kinda got no clue what's going on. Regardless, thank you for your help!

Comment: The vector sum is not equal to speed but its modulus or magnitude since speed is a scalar quantity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @SarGe . That makes sense haha. I understand the theory behind it. Thank you <3